# How can I make a contact the case manager of several cases with the same client contact?

Tags: civicase, relationships

Our organization is trying to use CiviCase as a ticketing system. So we have one case type, the "Ticket".

We can have multiple Tickets open for the same client. However, I can't assign the same contact as a "Case Manager" for multiple tickets to the same client.

So let's say client A has 2 open Tickets. On the first Ticket, I assign myself as the Case Manager. That works as expected. However, when I try to assign myself as the Case Manager of the second Ticket for client A, I get an error:

> The relationship type definition for the case role is not valid for the client and / or staff contact types.

If I create 2 cases to the same client, I am automatically assigned as a Case Manager to both of those cases. However, if I remove myself as Case Manager, and try to re-add myself, I get the same error as above.

How can I assign myself (or anybody else) as the Case Manager of multiple cases to the same client.

Comment: Which version of CiviCRM?

Comment: I'm running 4.6.0

Comment: We're running up against this after upgrading to 4.6.3. We were able to do it on 4.5 but lost the ability along the way.

Comment: We are also running up against this, but with *all* Case Roles-- not just the Case Manager.  We have also seen this introduced as a regression-- we upgraded from 4.5.4 to 4.6.4.

Answer (score 2):

So, I know it's against best practices, but after digging into the code a bit, I've located a (hacky) solution to my problem. When adding a Case Manager via a case view, CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship::legacyCreateMultiple is executed.

At line 194 there's a check for duplicate relationships. If I comment out the "*continue*" at line 203 within the dupe check, I can successfully assign the case manager to the case.

I would much rather not have to do a core edit, so I await a better solution.

Edit: I had run into a problem elsewhere that ended up being caused by my hack. I do not recommend implementing my hack as I'm not sure of the implications.

Comment: Did you file an issue in Jira for this?

Comment: This code must not fire if *changing* a contact as a role, but only if filling in a blank.  If a contact is trashed and added, it seems that the problem is encountered.  If a false contact is put in there and *changed* to the "problem contact", the system freely accepts the entry.

Comment: I can verify that this works for all of the Roles experiencing this problem, but I agree that this is outside of best practices.

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6439 fixes the issue!

Comment: Jitendra's solution worked for me.

Comment: Still facing this issue on CiviCRM 4.6.24 and Drupal 7.53 site. Does it have to do with the configuration?

Comment: If you change the relationship type of case co-ordinator and case manager to all contacts this resolves the error. Not sure if it relates to the exact scenario here but I was also getting the same popup error i.e. The relationship type definition for the case role is not valid for the client and / or staff contact types.